# How to change 'tabs' in my android app simply swiping on the screen? Like Google+ Android app does

Tags: android, android-layout, tabs, android-widget

in my android app I would like to create a ux like the new Google+ app for android, in wich moving from one tab to the other (for example viewing a user profile: 'post','info' and 'photos') is possible simply swiping on the screen..

Can anyone please help me providing some example or tutorial?

Thanks everyone in advance!

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/937313/android-basic-gesture-detection. There is working code for swipe detection, which you can adapt to your app.

Answer (score 4):

They're doing horizontal swiping with a ViewPager. Here's a [post on the android blog](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2011/08/horizontal-view-swiping-with-viewpager.html) about how to do that.